# How do l toggle item click in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do l toggle the id="tree" when any of the class="folder" is clicked? My implementation is not working. It keeps toggling only the first item no matter which class="folder" I click. Thanks for your help

```
 <div class="main">
   <ul class="collections>
      <li class="listitem1">
          <span class="folder"> folder  </span>
          <div id="tree">

               //...THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS

          </div>
    </li>
    <li class"listitem2">
          <span class="folder"> folder  </span>
          <div id="tree">

               //...THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS

          </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

`JS`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tree').slideToggle("fast");
  $('.folder').click(function() {
    $('#tree').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Comment: Post you script also which you have tried.

Comment: *My implementation is not working.*.... how so? And you should show us your implementation. Are your elements added dynamically by chance?

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript code?

Comment: ***ID should always be unique use class***. `It keeps toggling only the first item no matter which class="folder" I click` it is because it is toggling the `first tree ID` it encounters and dont care about the rest

Comment: Yes, they are populated dynamically. This is my code... <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#tree').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.folder').click(function() {
                $('#tree').slideToggle("fast");
   
       });
   
    });

  </script>

Comment: And you html code have many typo mistakes

Comment: You are missing **=** in your class attributes

Comment: @ketan I fixed that and still have the issue. Thanks for the spot on

Comment: @ErnestAppiah check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are **id** should be unique.

And there are some typo in your html code also. Like `=` sign is not there after class. And you forget to close the quote.

Use following JQuery.

```
$(this).siblings("div").slideToggle("fast");
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk2rkyr4)**

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.tree').slideToggle("fast");
  $('.folder').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.tree').slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
   <ul class="collections">
      <li class="listitem1">
          <span class="folder"> folder  </span>
          <div class="tree">

               THIS
          </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listitem2">
          <span class="folder"> folder  </span>
          <div class="tree">

               THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS

          </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Try using `.parent()` and then `.find()` to get the class `tree`

Answer (score 1):

Please change the **ID** in to a class, because **ID** is unique. Its not allowed  same multiple **ID** name in a document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tree').hide();
  $('.folder').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.tree').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
   <ul class="collections">
      <li class="listitem1">
          <span class="folder"> folder  </span>
          <div class="tree">

               //...THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS

          </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listitem2">
          <span class="folder"> folder  </span>
          <div class="tree">

               //...THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS

          </div>
    </li>
   </ul></div>
```